# Azure Runbook - [AzureAD] Get-AzureADUser -All

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-runbook

We are implementing a Runbook which has to get all AzureAD Users - The code seems running successful and we are getting the right count of users (6453) - however, while getting the output in a JSON format, it throws the following error: the runbook job failed due to a job stream being larger than 1MB, the limit that is supported by an Azure Automation sandbox. See some common ways to resolve this at https://aka.ms/AAjobstreamlimit

We have tried multiple permutations & combination to get the right output but no luck...

Please note that the same code works fine in a local machine (Windows 10) using Powershell.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
    
    # Logging in to Azure AD with Service Principal
    "Logging in to Azure AD..."
    Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

try{
    $AzureADUsers = Get-AzureADUser -All $true -Filter 'accountEnabled eq true' | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department
    $AzureADUsers.Count;

    try{
        Write-Output ($AzureADUsers| ConvertTo-Json)
    }
    catch{
        $AppException2 = $_.Exception
    }
}
catch{
    $AppException1 = $_.Exception
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you follow this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/runbooks#output-stream-greater-1mb

Comment: @JoyWang: Ensure that your runbook encloses calls to an executable or subprocess by using try and catch blocks. => its already done

Answer (score 1):

I test your code on my runbook, it works fine(There are just `251` users in my tenant).

[image]

The cause in this [scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/runbooks#output-stream-greater-1mb) is just a possible one, not every this error was caused by this issue.

From the lines below, obviously we can know the `1 MB` limit is on the runbook job output stream, the `try catch` blocks just prevents the message from being written into the job output stream, in your case, there are `6453` users in the tenant, I think it will also reach the limit, even if there is no error written into the output stream.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the sandbox stream limit of 1 MB and there is an old user vote for increasing the sandbox stream limit of 1 MB. Maybe it's worth to vote.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/15024291-change-behavior-when-sandbox-runs-out-of-memory-1

Therefore the solution is to split the query as follows:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | where-Object { $_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[a-j,A-J]'} | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | where-Object { $_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[k-t,K-T]'} | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | where-Object { $_.DisplayName -cmatch '^[u-z,U-Z]'} | select DisplayName,UserPrincipalName,Department
```